# How to get standalone self-contained copy of the AppleScript language documentation?

Tags: macos, applescript

Is there a way to get a copy of the AppleScript language documentation (specifically the [overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000156i) and [language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html)) in a self-contained form?  I could recursively download the HTML documentation from the Apple websites, but is there a better way?

*EDIT*:
My apologies for not being more specific: I know you can download the docs in PDF, but I'm trying to find them in a downloadable HTML format.

Answer (score 2):

How about the pdf link at the top of the page?

[image]

Comment: Argh, I'm sorry I wasn't more specific: I'm trying to find it in HTML format. I will edit my question.